# How to scale and position watermark to scale?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, scale, scaling, watermark

I'm scaling a video and applying a watermark like so:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:0:0.000 -i video.mp4 -y -an -t 0:0:10.000
 -vf \"[in]scale=400:316[middle]\" -b:v 2000k -r 20
 -vf 'movie=watermark.png,pad=400:316:0:0:0x00000000 [watermark];[middle] [watermark]overlay=0:0[out]'
 out.flv
```

However, the applied watermark seems to be scaled to the original video size rather than the smaller scaled video size.

This command line worked on ffmpeg version `0.8.6.git` and now behaves differently after an upgrade to version `N-52381-g2288c77`.

How do I get it to work again?

---

**Update 2013-04-26:**
I now have tried to use the overlay filter's X and Y parameters instead of padding without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered by *ubitux* on the FFmpeg IRC:

Use `scale` and `overlay` in a single `-filter_complex` chain, like so:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 0 -t 0:0:30.0 -i 'video.mp4' -i '/watermark.png'
 -filter_complex "[0:0] scale=400:225 [wm]; [wm][1:0] overlay=305:0 [out]"
 -map "[out]" -b:v 896k -r 20 -an 
 'out.flv'
```

Also load the watermark via `-i` rather than the `movie` filter.

Comment: Hum I have to say this has got me :D 
`Error initializing filter 'scale' with args '400:225:pad=height=ih+20:color=#71cbf4`